# How to get archive name while unzipping

Tags: ant

I am using ant unzip task to get contents of a archive file.

Is there a possibility to also save the name of that archive somehow.

Below is the code I am using to unzip an archive.

```
    <unzip dest="${import.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${tmp.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.zip"/>
        </fileset>   
    </unzip>
```

Regards,
Satya

Comment: Will you always only match one archive?  Or, what happens if you match more than one?  What do you need the name for - just to log or display - or something more?

Comment: Yes, the tmp.dir will always have only one zip. I need that archive nae to log in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an embedded groovy script

```
<target name="unzip">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy" classpathref="build.path"/>

    <fileset id="zips" dir="${tmp.dir}" includes="**/*.zip"/>

    <groovy>
        project.references.zips.each { file ->
            ant.echo(message:"message goes here", file:"build.log", append:true)
            ant.unzip(src:file, dest:properties["import.dir"])
        }
    </groovy>
</target>
```

Groovy task is documented [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task)